# Is there a better way to create a water year datetime column in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

For one of my projects I need to change from a calendar year to water year and have it in the YYYY-MM-DD format.  A common definition of a [water year](http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Water_year) is October 1 - September 30th, which is what I am going for.  I have drafted some code that works, but I feel like there is a better way to approach this and I wanted to see if anyone has any suggestions.

I start out by creating the monthly date range I am interested in:

```
import pandas as pd
date = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('1915-01-01', '2011-12-31', freq='MS'))
date.columns = ['Date']
Date = date['Date']
date_set = date.set_index(Date)
print(date_set)
```

Which prints the following:

```
    Date
0    1915-01-01
1    1915-02-01
2    1915-03-01
3    1915-04-01
4    1915-05-01
        ...
1159 2011-08-01
1160 2011-09-01
1161 2011-10-01
1162 2011-11-01
1163 2011-12-01
```

Now use a function to set the WY, where the months October through December get +1 added to their year:

```
def convert_to_WY(row):
    if row['Date'].month>=10:
        return(pd.datetime(row['Date'].year+1,1,1).year)
    else:
        return(pd.datetime(row['Date'].year,1,1).year)

date_set['WaterYear'] = date_set.apply(lambda x: convert_to_WY(x), axis=1)
```

This works and gives me a column called "WaterYear" where it lists the year based on the conditions specified in the function.  I want the WaterYear column to have the format YYYY-MM-DD and the way I went about this is shown below:

```
date_set['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(date_set['Date']).month
date_set['Day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(date_set['Date']).day
date_set['WaterYear_F'] = date_set.apply(lambda row: datetime(row['WaterYear'], row['Month'], row['Day']), axis=1)
date_set.drop(['Month','Day','WaterYear','Date'], axis=1, inplace = True)
print(date_set.head(15))
```

After printing the result I got was what I wanted:

```
           WaterYear_F
Date                  
1915-01-01  1915-01-01
1915-02-01  1915-02-01
1915-03-01  1915-03-01
1915-04-01  1915-04-01
1915-05-01  1915-05-01
1915-06-01  1915-06-01
1915-07-01  1915-07-01
1915-08-01  1915-08-01
1915-09-01  1915-09-01
1915-10-01  1916-10-01
1915-11-01  1916-11-01
1915-12-01  1916-12-01
1916-01-01  1916-01-01
1916-02-01  1916-02-01
1916-03-01  1916-03-01
```

I just feel like this is a very roundabout way to do this and am looking for any tips or suggestions to clean this up some.

Comment: What *is* a "water year"?

Comment: This is outright strange. Why would you convert the entire date? When dealing with a _fiscal year_ we might reference the _Fiscal Year 2021_, but the calendar year is **never** converted from `2020/16/07` to `2021/16/07`

Comment: `date.Date.dt.to_period('Q-SEP').dt.qyear`?

Comment: I agree, it is strange.  I am converting it mostly because of the data format for the model I am going to input data into requires this (I wish it werent so).  Quang, I like the suggestions and that is a much more concise way to get this to water year.  What about converting that year to the proper date format yyyy-mm-dd?  Is there a more concise way to do that?

Comment: Karl, see http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Water_year for a better description.

Comment: I would just create a column of an integer holding the "water year" like a fiscal year as an *integer* not as a *datetime* which should be easy to compute given the actual dates.  Then you would have an accurate WY label associated with the *actual* date and allow you to sort by WY or actual date, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is efficient, but as you point out, it requires several steps. Why not just do this:

```
import pandas as pd

date_range = pd.date_range('1915-01-01', '2011-12-31', freq='MS')
date_df = pd.DataFrame(date_range, columns=['Date'])

def adjust_to_water_year(date):
    if date.month >= 10:
        return date.replace(year=date.year + 1)
    return date

date_df['WaterYear_F'] = date_df['Date'].apply(adjust_to_water_year)
date_df['WaterYear_F'] = date_df['WaterYear_F'].dt.to_period('D').astype(str)

print(date_df.head(15))
```

which gives you what you expected as output

```
         Date WaterYear_F
0  1915-01-01  1915-01-01
1  1915-02-01  1915-02-01
2  1915-03-01  1915-03-01
3  1915-04-01  1915-04-01
4  1915-05-01  1915-05-01
5  1915-06-01  1915-06-01
6  1915-07-01  1915-07-01
7  1915-08-01  1915-08-01
8  1915-09-01  1915-09-01
9  1915-10-01  1916-10-01
10 1915-11-01  1916-11-01
11 1915-12-01  1916-12-01
12 1916-01-01  1916-01-01
13 1916-02-01  1916-02-01
14 1916-03-01  1916-03-01
```